# How to copy text between 2 symbols[keywords] in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I replace text between 2 symbols, in my case `"." and "/"` (without the quotes)

While doing some research at Stack, I found some answers, but they didn't help much.

I think the problem is using common operators as a part of string.

I tried using split

```
var a = "example.com/something"
var b = a.split(/[./]/);
var c = b[0];
```

I also tried this:

```
srctext = "example.com";
var re = /(.*.\s+)(.*)(\s+/.*)/;
var newtext = srctext.replace(re, "$2");
```

But the above 2 didn't seem to work.

I would be real glad if someone were to solve the question and please explain the use of escape sequences using an example or two. For a side note, I tried Googling it up but the data was not too helpful for me.

Comment: `"example.com/something".replace(/\..*?\//, '')`

Comment: @Tushar That also matched the `.` and the `/`.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @Tushar The question says *How do I replace text between 2 symbols*, so I would think he is trying to replace `com` with something else.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Okay, added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
var a = "example.com/something";
var textToChange = 'org';
var result = a.replace(/(\.)([\w]+)(\/)/, '$1' + textToChange + '$3');
```

result will be `example.org/something`

`$1` equals `.`

`$2` is the string you want to change

`$3` equals `/`

Currently I only assumed the text you want to change is mixture of alphabets. You can change `[\w]+` to any regular expression to fit the text you want to change.

Comment: Can I copy the text, i.e "com"

Comment: You can. `var match = a.match(/(\.)([\w]+)(\/)/);`. The string you want is `match[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegEx `\..*?\/` with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove anything that is between the `.` and `/`.

```
"example.com/something".match(/\.(.*?)\//)[1] // com
```

**RegEx Explanation:**

1. `\.`: Match `.` literal
2. `(.*?)`: Match anything except newline, non-greedy and add it in first captured group
3. `\/`: Match forward slash

Comment: I think `example.com/something".replace(/\..*?\//, '.\co.uk/')` could also be  useful here - replaces the `.com` with `.co.uk`.

Comment: @MikeChamberlain Sorry, I don't understand that, is that mentioned in question?

Comment: @Tushar Thanks for the awesome answer and well written explanation.

Comment: @MikeChamberlain Understand it now!

Answer (score 1):

The example given in your question will work if you make a small change

```
var a = "example.com/something"
var b = a.split(/[./]/);
var c = b[1];
alert(c);
```

`b[1]` will give you string between `.` and `/` not b[0]

Answer (score 0):

something as simple as

```
var a = "example.com/something"
var c = a.substring( a.indexOf( "." ) + 1, a.indexOf( "/", a.indexOf( "." ) ) );
alert(c);
```

for replacing,

```
a = a.replace( c, "NEW" );
alert(a);
```

to replace it with quotes

```
a = a.replace( c, "\"\"" );
alert(a);
```

Comment: The above solution on JSfiddling gives "e.com" as the result, but I just need "com" as the result.

Comment: @SaumyaBanthia check now

Comment: @Tushar it gives `duckduckgo.com` isn't that the intended response? Or the last `.` before `/` should be consisdered?

Comment: Unclear to me too, so added comment on question, OP didn't respond.

Comment: Actually as @Tushar mentioned. I need it for getting  the "com"